# Iam Created Login Form but here If I login twice only it redirects the page in django

Tags: html, django, authentication, redirect

Here My Html Code `I am` created an Login Form

Here my action is empty if I give an `URL` in action `means. Then` I will submit means it will goes to next page without authentication.

Please Help me out...If I am login means it will redirect to the Page Dash. But here i want to login twice only means then it works successfully...If I login only once means it `does'nt`  redirect the page I don't know why

```
<form  action="" method="post"> 
{%csrf_token%}
<div class="form-outline mb-4">
 <input  type="text" name="username" id="form3Example3" class="form-control form-control-lg" class="form-control new-input" placeholder="Enter a Name" required>
<label class="form-label" for="form3Example3"></label>
</div>
<div class="form-outline mb-3">
 <input type="password" name="password" id="form3Example4" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter password" required>
 <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4"></label>
 </div>
                   
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
 <div class="form-check mb-0">
 <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value="" id="form2Example3" />
 <label class="form-check-label" for="form2Example3">Remember me</label>
 </div>
<a href="#!" class="text-body">Forgot password?</a>
</div>
<div class="text-center text-lg-start mt-4 pt-2">
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="register-button2" />
</form>
<p class="small fw-bold mt-2 pt-1 mb-0">Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'register'%}"
 class="link-danger">Register</a></p>
</div>
```

Views.py

```
def Login(request):
           if request.method=='POST':
             username=request.POST['username']
             password=request.POST['password']
             user=auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
             if user is not None:
                 request.session['user'] = username
                 auth.login(request,user)
                 print(user)
                 return redirect('Dash')
          else: 
            messages.info(request,'invalid credientials')
                  return redirect('Login') 
           else:
                return render(request,'Login.html')
```

This is the Dash View after login redirects the page.Here Dash View after login successfully

```
 def Dash(request):
        if 'user' in request.session:
            print("INSIDE THE DASH")
            current_user = request.session['user']
            param = {'current_user': current_user}
            return render(request,'Dash.html',param)
        else:
            return redirect('Login')
```

After Login successfully the page does'nt redirect to the next page...and again i will login with same username and password only it will login and redirect the page i don't know why please help me somebody

Comment: Try passing the `url` instead of the view name in your **redirect()** function. For example `redirect('/login')` or `/dashboard` etc. 
For detail https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: To my understanding your login is successful but your are not able to redirect to `Dash` route, right?